# Adding subview blade sections dynamically to a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I plan to add "extras" to many pages, assume extras are from an infinite amount.

It's a bit hard to explain using words so i will do my best explaining it through file structure i have in mind

```
-Views
 -Products
  -Prodcut.blade.php
 -Extras
  -extra1
   - extra_pricing.blade.php
   - extra_tab.blade.php
  -extra2
   - extra_tab.blade.php
  ..
  -extra100
```

now i want these "extras" in "Extra" folder , to yield in Product page , each in their appropriate space ( For exmaple: extra_tab will be in a < ul > ), these extras file will be submitted by user and added automatically.

Also it will not only be done in **Product.blade.php** , other extras should match to other pages.

Answer (score 2):

Rethink your implementation. There should not be `Extras/extra{#}/extra_tab.blade.php` for an "infinite" (unknown?) number, or any for that matter. The differences between `Extras/extra1/extra_tab.blade.php` and `Extras/extra2/extra_tab.blade.php` should be determined by logic/parameter passed to the view partial.

Instead, a structure would have one `extra_tab.blade.php` file like so:

```
Extras/extra_tab.blade.php
```

Wherein `extra_tab.blade.php` can receive a parameter (such as an ID) like so:

#### Product.blade.php

```
@foreach($extra_tabs as $key => $tab)
   @include('Extras.extra_tab', array('key' => $key, 'tab' => $tab))
@endforeach
```

#### Extras/extra_tab.blade.php

```
<?php 
echo "This tab has index: ${key}. Here is the tab: \n"; 
print_r($tab);
?>
```